# How to cache user's preferred language on a multi-language website?

Tags: php, html, css, caching

**Hej y'all!** I'm currently working on implementing multi-language for my personal website. So far I've created two php files with arrays for the german & english translations which then get's loaded, based on the selected language, on my website using the `require_once("")`-method. I'd need to reload the website after the user changes the language to reload the content with the correct translation. But after reloading the page, the selection would of course be reseted. My question now is: How can I cache the selected language?

Comment: Typically you'd look at the [`Accept-Language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language) request header. The browser basically tells the server what language it prefers, and this value is avalable on every request. Alternatively, if you want to override that, just store the desired choice in a cookie.

Comment: I don't like smart-ass pages which decide for me, and give me no choice. I use structure - each language has its own direction, and links to others are provided on each page. The user can bookmark www.page/en/something and if s/he want to change the language flag-link redirects directly to www/page/other_language/something. No sessions, no cookie, no junk

Comment: @blackblue but then you'd have to create a ton of copies of one page to deploy it into the right directory with the specific translation, or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: you misunderstood little, I'm a coder, to make new language version I must add language code (like en, de, la) into one array, (of course translate at least major nav terms ) and run one function. To fix or change existing versions all I need is - fix/change this one function and run it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) (or a [regular cookie](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)) and store the code of your language (or whatever identificator you use during the selection).

```
$_SESSION['loc'] = 'en-us';
```

Then you can check that session variable.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['loc']) && $_SESSION['loc'] === 'en-us'){
    //English
} else { 
//Other language, or language not selected
}
```

You might want to grab a language based on the browser too, you could cache it something like this:

```
$lang = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2));

$accepting = ['en', 'ge'];
$code = in_array($lang, $accepting) ? $lang : 'en';

$_SESSION['localization'] = $code; //Or a regular cookie
```

Comment: I think I'd really like a mix of both solutions here. When there is no session, load the page with the browser's language (if that's a supported language, otherwise in english), but if a session exists, load the page with the language associated with the session. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I do for this is set the user's language preference on the session, and also persist it to a cookie for long-term storage. When the user returns, my session class looks for the cookie and sets the language code in the new session.

Here's an example that uses Zend_Session, and has language detection, but the parts that save and retrieve the language preference are pretty simple, you could adapt it to any situation.

```
<?php
class UserSession extends Zend_Session_Namespace
{
    public function __construct($namespace = 'user')
    {
        Zend_Session::start();

        parent::__construct($namespace);

        $defaultLanguageCode = 'EN-US';

        if (empty($this->languageCode) && isset($_COOKIE['userprefs']))
        {
            //Fail silently if the prefs json is corrupt
            try
            {
                $prefs = Zend_Json::decode($_COOKIE['userprefs']);

                $this->languageCode = $prefs['languageCode'];
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
            }
        }

        //Detect language, and set on session if we support it
        if (!isset($this->languageCode))
        {
            $locale = new Zend_Locale();

            $lang = $locale->getLanguage();

            //Reformat
            $lang = strtoupper(str_replace('_', '-', $lang));

            if (!is_null($lang) && $lang != '')
            {
                $languageCode = $defaultLanguageCode;

                $conditions = array(
                    array('active', '=', 1),
                    array('code', '=', $lang)
                );

                $languageFac = Busobj_Language::objFactory($conditions);
                $language    = $languageFac->getFirst();

                if ($language instanceof Busobj_Language)
                {
                    $languageCode = $language->getCode();
                }
                elseif (strpos($lang, '-') !== false)
                {
                    //If we don't get a hit and there is a region in the code, strip back to the lang and try again
                    $lang       = (substr($lang, strpos($lang, '-')));
                    $conditions = array(
                        array('active', '=', 1),
                        array('code', '=', $lang)
                    );

                    $languageFac = Busobj_Language::objFactory($conditions);
                    $language    = $languageFac->getFirst();

                    if ($language instanceof Busobj_Language)
                    {
                        $languageCode = $language->getCode();
                    }
                }

                $this->setLanguageCode($languageCode);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->setLanguageCode($defaultLanguageCode);
            }
        }
    }

    public function sendPrefsCookie()
    {
        $prefs = array(
            'languageCode' => $this->languageCode
        );

        $prefsJson = Zend_Json::encode($prefs);

        setcookie('userprefs', $prefsJson, time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365), '/', FW_DOMAIN);
    }

    public function setLanguageCode($languageCode)
    {
        $this->languageCode = $languageCode;
        $this->sendPrefsCookie();
    }

    public function __sleep()
    {
        return array('languageCode');
    }

    public function __wakeup()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an awesome solution!
Unfortunately I am not soo familiar with PHP & I don't like copy-pasting without understanding what's done there so I'll probably go with the other solution which was commented here for now. But I'll absolutely look back in the future & consider implementing your method when I'm more familiar with PHP - Thanks!